# How do I add a cookie so that when my local Excel sheet connects to my remote Excel on WordPress database, it is allowed?

Tags: excel, vba, wordpress, cookies

I have an Excel file on WordPress which will be the recipient of the data in the form of adding new rows.
Let's call this **excel-r** (recipient).
I have a local Excel file, lets call this **excel-d** (donor).

excel-r is located in my WordPress/uploads folder, which normally is accessible as a read, with owner permissions of all (read write and execute) (file permission code is 755). However I have used htaccess to lock this folder to only users who are logged in using the code.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?/?)wp-content/uploads/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule . http://%{HTTP_HOST}%1/wp-login.php?redirect_to=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Additionally on my functions.php I have code that grants access through the firewall by giving them a login cookie. (This prevents firewall from blocking them as brute force bots.)

```
function your_own_function(){
 if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/login/' ) :
   if ( ! isset( $_COOKIE['login_cookie'] ) ) :
       setcookie( 'login_cookie', 10DIGITCOOKIECODEHERE, time() + 3600 * 24 * 100, '/', 'DOMAIN.COMHERE', false);
   endif;
 endif;
}
```

In Excel, I go to developer tab and open up visual basic which is fairly simple it sets some variables for **excel-r** such as setting the filename, and folderpath, and then connects to it and paste the data into the specific cells.

How can I add a cookie so that when it tries to connect to the folderpath, it will be allowed?

I found this code on another website, but I'm not sure where to put it, or if the cookie name has to be specific and whatnot.

```vb
Dim myCookie As HttpCookie = New HttpCookie("UserSettings")
myCookie("Font") = "Arial"
myCookie("Color") = "Blue"
myCookie.Expires = Now.AddDays(1)
Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out that this strategy to connect to an Excel sheet in a Wordpress database and open it, is quite hard through HTTP using cookies, or atleast I couldn't understand how, as it would require a cookie, and somehow deliver that cookie, and then somehow download and open the excel-r in HTTP which might not even be possible.

Therefore, instead, I used VBA connecting to wordpress server via FTP. This was actually much easier by just changing the filepath to ftp://user:pass@server/directory

The only issue that I have NOW is that when Excel uses VBA to connect to the Wordpress file server via ftp... it treats it completely differently than if it was a local file.
It does NOT treat it like as if you opened it from filezilla.
The issue is that it cannot OVERWRITE a file when using ftp. This really sucks.

So now I am in the process of having to open excel-r. make changes to excel-r-c (changed).
Then save excel-r-c.
Then delete excel-r.
Then rename excel-r-c to excel-r.

lol

A very annoying and dumb process all becuase Microsoft seemingly doesn't let me overwrite a file when opening via ftp. sadge